# Robin's inequality and highly composite numbers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I know for a fact that for all $n > 5040$ there is no violation for robin's inequality from square-full,square-free numbers,i also know that in order for a number to violate robin's inequality then the number have the form :

$N =p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2} \cdots p_r^{k_r} * p_{r+1} p_{r+2} \cdots p_{m}$

such that $k_i \geq 2$ for all $i$ and the prime in ascending order, also the $k_i$ sequence is non-increasing sequence.

all the above i know from paul erdos paper on the matter,**but what i really don't understand is the following**

does mathematicans know that $p_r = O(\sqrt{p_m}) $ ?!, i think erdos paper give this bound on $p_r$ but i am not sure, any ref to a paper proving these bounds or deeper insight to the problem would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how are $m$ and $r$ related? if $m=r+1$, then false

Comment: @mathworker21 because paul proved they are in ascending order so it's easy to conclude that $r < m$ but my question is by how much, does $r << m$ or does $p_r = O(\sqrt{p_m})$

Comment: It don't understand your question. The Robin inequality is mainly for primorials, then it is not hard to show it works for all integers. Why do you care of the highly composite numbers. If you want to find exactly for which integers Robin's inequality fails under the assumption that $\zeta$ has a zero at $\sigma$ then see Lagarias Robin's papers, estimating $\prod_{p^k \| n} (1+p^{-1}+\ldots+p^{-k})$ for $n =( \# q)^a \# r$